# Replace HTML encoded line breaks with <br /> using regular expression

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

Within my application users are able to post messages. I use the following c# code to remove harmful HTML from the posted message:

```
System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode(_message, true);
```

One of the requirements is that line breaks should be preserved in the message when it is printed on the screen. With the above code linebreaks are converted to `&#10;`. To resolve this I am trying to replace those characters with `<br />` using a regular expression but I can't figure out the correct regular expression.

Using the tester at regexlib.com I can easily filter out all the single '&' or all the '#10;' but not with the '&' in front of it.

How can I do this?

Comment: Where are you replacing the `&#10;`, in C# or JS? What does your code look like?

Comment: Why not use a *pre* element, which will preserve whitespace?

Comment: so are you saying that your users can paste html in an input field? If so simply encode the input and decode before printing on screen in a <pre> tag

Comment: In javascript, using the following code:
return this.message.text.replace(/(?:(#([1]{1}[0]{1};)))/g, "<br>");

Answer (score 0):

As @RobG and @NoviceProgrammer pointed out the `<pre>`-tag did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Regex.Replace` to make the replacements. Not sure about if the capturing group (parenthesis) in the Regex is really neeeded. Sample call:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("(&#10;)");
string safeWithBreakLines = rgx.Replace(safeInput, "<br />");
```